isomorphism of Galois group (semidirect product)
Suppose $K$ is the smallest splitting field of $f=x^4-2x^2-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.
The solution of $f$ is $x=\pm\alpha,\pm\beta$ , when  $\alpha :=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}},\beta:=\sqrt{1-\sqrt{2}}$ .
Now, $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1},\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2},\alpha)$ .
I will use the following theorem (Japanese call this theorem "Galois's propulsion theorem". But, I cannot find the English name of this theorem.).

Let $L/K$ be finite  Galois extension, $M,N$ be a intermediate field such that $M/K$ is Galois extension and $L=MN,K=M\cap N$. The following holds in this situation.
\begin{equation}
Gal(L/K)\cong Gal(L/M)\rtimes Gal(L/N) .
\end{equation}
The semidirect product is formed by the action of the latter group on the former group via conjugation

The following holds when the above theorem is applied to the current situation.
\begin{align}
Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})&\cong Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1}))\rtimes Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)) \\
&\cong Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1}))\rtimes Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})/\mathbb{Q})\\
&\cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}
\end{align}
On the other hand, if we let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2},\alpha)$, the following holds
\begin{align}
Gal(K/\mathbb{Q})&\cong Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2}))\rtimes Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)) \\
&\cong Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-2}))\rtimes Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})/\mathbb{Q})\\
&\cong \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \\
&\cong D_4
\end{align}
I found this puzzling. Are $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^2 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $D_4$ really isomorphic? And is such a strange isomorphism valid?
Regarding the classification of groups of order 8 and the fact that the quaternion group cannot be written as a semidirect product, it seems that the former group is isomorphic to the dihedral group. However, I cannot actually verify that these two are isomorphic. How can I confirm that they are indeed isomorphic?

Pick an element $x$ in $C_2^2$ which is not fixed by $y$, the generator of the $C_2$ complement in the semidirect product. Show $xy$ has order $4$, so that $\langle x,y\rangle$ is the dihedral group.

You did well figuring it out. The first group ain't $Q_8$ (in addition to your argument you can use the fact that $Q_8$ has only one element of order two). The suggestion by Steve is great, and possibly the simplest way of producing an explicit automorphism. For a bit of extra, you may want to look at wreath products. The first way of looking at it gives the group as the wreath product $\Bbb{Z}_2\wr\Bbb{Z}_2$, and there is a somewhat natural (faithful) action of that group on a set of four elements.

(cont'd) Once you have the group as a subgroup of $S_4$, then, for reasons of cardinality, it must be a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $S_4$. That is, $\simeq D_4$.

Thank you @SteveD. I don't understand the meaning of "fixed by $y$". Is $y$ the element of $Gal(Q(\sqrt{-1})/Q)$ such that $y:\sqrt{-1}\mapsto -\sqrt{-1}$ ?

Thank you @JyrkiLahtonen. I searched about wreath products, but it was still difficult. I hope to understand it in the future. Thank you for providing me with new insights.

D'oh! Of course, the group is a subgroup of $S_4$ as a collection of permutations of the roots of $f$. So it is a Sylow 2 in there, and hence $\simeq D_4$. Don't need wreath product actions to get it to act faithfully on a set of four elements :-). Though it is still a useful exercise to work out that action, too.
